# access to variable within inner class

Tags: android

I have a list and I want to set its OnItemLongClickListener to show a TimePickerDialog.

The problem is that the Picker can't get any value from the item calling it.

```
    lst_meetings.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                    if (timePicker.isShown())finishMeeting(Integer.parseInt(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_No)).getText().toString()),String.format("%02d", i) + ":" + String.format("%02d", i1) + ":00");
                }
            },0,0,false);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Finish Time");
            timePickerDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[Setting `view` as final is not allowed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0nGR.png)

How to pass `View` to the anonymous class.

Comment: I believe it already passes in the view of the item that was clicked on, is there a different view you want to access? (edit: shoot I didn't look close enough, Abkarino has got your back)

Comment: The Code above have a compiler error in
(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_No)

Comment: @ultifinitus I must make view final to use it in the onTimeSet handler. But that breaks the code.

Comment: @Abkarino How does it break the code when you make the parameter final, i.e. `final View view`?

Comment: @DanielNugent I edited the post and added an image. It just makes the whole code red and says you can't use it.

Comment: @Abkarino Strange, that didn't happen with me in Android Studio.  You could try creating a temp variable, I posted an answer earler but deleted it.  I'll undelete it now, let me know if it helps you at all.  Note I also changed `this` to `MainActivity.this`, as just using `this` might be out of scope in this code block.  Obviously, modify `MainActivity` with the name of your Activity you have this code in.

Comment: @DanielNugent Did you say that you tried the code and it worked ?!

Comment: @Abkarino Ok, sorry that it didn't help, I re-deleted the answer since it didn't solve your problem.  I'll take another look when I have time.  Note that I didn't run the code, but it compiled in Android Studio.  However, it also compiled by just making the View final in the parameter.

Comment: @DanielNugent I saw a comment on your answer saying something about `this`. Did you change the context in your answer ?

Comment: @Abkarino Yes, look at the comment above.  Just make sure that you have a valid Context, I put in `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` (MainActivity being a place-holder for the name of the Activity you're using).  `new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,..........`

Comment: @DanielNugent The `final` with `MainActivity.this` solved it.
Please undelete the answer and point to the context point to accept it.

Comment: @Abkarino Really?  Great!  Ok, just undeleted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a temporary `final View` that will be visible in the `onTimeSet()` method.

Also make sure that you have a valid Context for the `TimePickerDialog`, so use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` (Replace `MainActivity` with your Activity name).

Try this:

```
       lst_meetings.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

                final View tempView = view; //added

                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                        // use tempView here:
                        if (timePicker.isShown())finishMeeting(Integer.parseInt(((TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.txt_No)).getText().toString()),String.format("%02d", i) + ":" + String.format("%02d", i1) + ":00");
                    }
                },0,0,false);
                timePickerDialog.setTitle("Finish Time");
                timePickerDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just glancing at the code - `this` needs to refer to a context.

Comment: I tried that solution and I even tried to create the variable at the start of the activity and yet it breaks the code like the picture.

Comment: @Abkarino  Ahh, ok.  Very strange.

Comment: @JaredRummler You helped a lot. Thanks.